# Writing an expression that displays the first and last initials of a name

Tags: python

```
s= 'Jon Wayne'
x= s.index(' ')
value=s[1]+x
print(value)
```

I am struggling to grasp how to get the program to automatically get the letter that appears after the space .

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first letter from each word

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

From the docs:

```
Strings can be indexed (subscripted), with the first character having index 0
```

And here is an example:

```
>>> name = 'Jon Wayne' 
>>> initial = ''.join((word[0] for word in name.split()))
>>> initial
'JW'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "Jon Wayne"
bits = name.split(" ")   # ['Jon', 'Wayne']
for bit in bits:
    print bit[0]         #  J W
```